# i have a problem extracting weekly billboard chart data for 10 years

Tags: python

**I am trying to extract weekly billboard charts data for 10 years. First I made a list of dates using this code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start="01/01/2010" 
last="01/01/2021"
start_date=datetime.strptime(start,"%d/%m/%Y")
last_date=datetime.strptime(last,"%d/%m/%Y")
dates=[]
while start_date <= (last_date - timedelta(days=7)):
    start_date += timedelta(days=7)
    dates.append(start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
print(dates)
```

**After I tried to extract data with this code but I get "IndexError: list index out of range".**

```
import billboard
billresults = []
for j in range(len(dates)):
    chart = billboard.ChartData('jazz-songs', date=start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))[j]
    entry =  [song.title,song.artist]
    billresults.append(entry)
    
billboardjazz = pd.DataFrame(data = billresults)
billboardjazz.columns = ['track_name','artist_name']  
print(billboardjazz)
```

**Is it correct to extract data this way and how should I deal with the error?
Thank you!**

Comment: The valid index range for a ChartData object (containing at least 1 item) will be 0 <= index < len(ChartData). In this case, your variable j obviously doesn't fit those criteria. When you overcome that issue, you'll then have a problem with the undefined variable named 'song'. Furthermore, your dataframe is going to be virtually useless unless you can work out what chart date an entry came from. You don't seem to be allowing for that. Also, there's no need to pre-construct a list of dates. Set a start date, add an interval to it as you run your loop and check if it goes beyond the end date

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have updated the code based on your comments:                                                                                                   `billresults = []
for i in range(30):
 chart = billboard.ChartData('jazz-songs', date=start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))[i]
 entry =  [chart.title,chart.artist]
 billresults.append(entry)
billboardjazz = pd.DataFrame(data = billresults)
billboardjazz.columns = ['track_name','artist_name']  
print(billboardjazz)`

Comment: It does not allow me to enter a range of more than 30, and I get a one-week chart. How can I adjust the code so I do not need to pre-construct a list of dates? I assume this is why I can not get a range of more than 30.

Comment: The code change (which you've unfortunately placed in comments) will fail if ChartData has fewer than 30 elements

Comment: With this code, I get exactly 30 tracks which is one-week chart. But I am aiming to get all weekly charts for 10 years. You mentioned before that I have to "Set a start date, add an interval to it as you run your loop and check if it goes beyond the end date". How should I do this? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find this helpful. For testing purposes I have a shorter timeframe and larger interval (time delta). Adjust for your needs.

```
import billboard
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
billresults = []
current_date = datetime.strptime('2010/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime('2010/12/31', '%Y/%m/%d')
delta = timedelta(days=30)
while current_date < end_date:
    ds = current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(f'Fetching chart for {ds}')
    for ce in billboard.ChartData('jazz-songs', date=ds):
        billresults.append([ce.title, ce.artist])
    current_date += delta
billboardjazz = pd.DataFrame(billresults)
billboardjazz.columns = ['Track', 'Artist']
print(billboardjazz)
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code and got the data I needed. Thank you for your help!